# multiple images in one line produce 1px position error

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

Im currently having a problem with several images in one line. they are next to each other but every picture after the first one is moved down by one pixel.

maybe someone has an idea as I dont :(

link: *removed*
(the lower portfolio part is what I am talking about)

html

```css
#protfolio_sec .all-portfolios {
  margin-top : 20px;
  margin-left : -10px;
}
#protfolio_sec .single-portfolio {
  float : left;
  margin-bottom : 10px;
  width : 277px;
}
#protfolio_sec .single-portfolio:hover .img_hoverlay {
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-portfolios">
  <div class="col-sm-12  col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="single-portfolio web-design">
 <a href="http://google.de" target="_blank" class="image-border"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/ptf/pre/test.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>    
  </div>    
  <div class="col-sm-12  col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="single-portfolio web-design">
 <a href="http://google.de" target="_blank" class="image-border"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/ptf/pre/test.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>  
  </div>    
</div>
```

would be great if someone could help.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css your custom css

```
.all-portfolios div[class*=col-]
{
min-height:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Did exactly what I wanted!